# Finding capacitance of this setup

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, capacitance

Let's say there is a capacitor of the following setup:
A parallel plate capacitor of area A, plate separation d and capacitance C is filled with three different dielectric materials having dielectric constants K1, K2 and K3.[image]
My tuition teacher told me that we were supposed to divide the dielectric with dielectric constant K3 into two parts like and then find the equivalent capacitance of this system to find C like this:
[image]

The reason he gave was that when you are trying to find the capacitance you need to start from one of the plate of the capacitor and reach the other one.

My school teacher told me this method to solve this question:
[image]

He said we were supposed to decide the capacitor in three different capacitors like this and then find the equivalent capacitance, which would give the value of C. Which one would give the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your school teacher is incorrect. Modeling the bottom dielectric as a single capacitor as in your last diagram assumes that the plane midway between the capacitor plates is an equipotential surface: i.e. it treats this interface as if there were a metal plate here (the upper plate of capacitor 3 in your diagram), keeping the potential uniform. The interfaces between dielectrics 1, 3 and dielectrics 2, 3 will be at different potentials if $K_1 \ne K_2$, so this schematic is not accurate. Your tuition teacher's schematic is right (neglecting fringing fields between dielectrics 1 and 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it